# Kinetic JS - Is there a way to return x,y coordinates while dragging?

Tags: kineticjs

I am making a toggle slider that moves up and down with Kinetic JS. Here is my draggable toggle:

```
this.toggle = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: (this.stage.getWidth() / 2) - 20,
        y: 210,
        shadowColor: '#95BA91',
        shadowOffsetX: 5,
        shadowOffsetY: 5,
        width: 40,
        height: 15,
        fill: '#FFF',
        cornerRadius: 3,
        draggable: true,
        dragBoundFunc: function( pos ) {
            return {
                x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
                y: pos.y
            }
        }
    });
```

I am trying to return the y coordinate of the toggle so I can increment a counter based on the toggle's height.  Every method I have tried returns the original value of y during and after the drag. Is there a way to get the changed y value?  Here are the methods I already have tried:

getY(), getAbsolutePosition().y, dragDistance(), .y(), getOffset().y, getPosition().y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the use of `dragBoundFunc`.

`dragBoundFunc` is mainly used to restrict in some way the movement of the shape when it is being dragged.

What you should do is attach a `dragmove` event listener to your toggle shape, which will fire when you're dragging the shape.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fds66/12/)

The Y coordinate is being printed in the browser's console everytime the toggle shape is being dragged.